# What is the syntax for adding the perticular extension type files in Jgit

Tags: git, jgit

I have a script that generates some ions file, I want to add these files in the staging area , for that I used

```
git.add()
.addFilepattern(".")
.call();
```

***With this I am able to add all files successfully,***

But for safe side, I want to add only the "ION" files to the staging area.When I used
this perticular syntax:

```
git.add()
.addFilepattern("*.ion")
.call();
```

***I am no longer able to add the files successfully.***

Is It some syntax error in my above command? Please provide some insight in this, how can I able to do this correctly via Jgit.

Comment: What version of jgit are you using? At least in older versions, file globs aren't supported at all. I don't know if this feature was ever added, for that matter.

Comment: JGit's `addFilePattern` does not support file globs (yet), see the JavaDoc: https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.12.0.202106070339-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html#addFilepattern-java.lang.String-

Comment: thanks Herrmann, yes you are right seems like file globs not supported yet. Thanks